# CSS - float: right - div height is so tight

Tags: css

I'm trying to create my web page but I have problem with float.

Here is my code HTML:

```
    <div id="RightBox"><div class="Title">Informacje</div><br>Autokoder.pl jest obecnie najbardziej innowacyjną i najszybciej rozwijającą się aplikacją służącą do obsługi aukcji Allegro.<br><br>Z naszego serwisu mogą korzystać zarówno sprzedający jak i kupujący użytkownicy Allegro. Zapewniamy dla naszych użytkowników szeroki wybór usług płatnych oraz darmowych.<br><br>Tylko u nas masz pewność, że Twoje kody zostaną bezproblemowo dostarczone do klienta. Dbamy także o dobro Twoje i kupującego informując błyskawicznie poprzez e-mail o braku dostępnych kodów.<br><br>Autokoder.pl jest obecnie najbardziej innowacyjną i najszybciej rozwijającą się aplikacją służącą do obsługi aukcji Allegro.<br><br>Z naszego serwisu mogą korzystać zarówno sprzedający jak i kupujący użytkownicy Allegro. Zapewniamy dla naszych użytkowników szeroki wybór usług płatnych oraz darmowych.<br><br>Tylko u nas masz pewność, że Twoje kody zostaną bezproblemowo dostarczone do klienta. Dbamy także o dobro Twoje i kupującego informując błyskawicznie poprzez e-mail o braku dostępnych kodów.</div>

    <div id="movie">
        <div class="Movie_Title"><a href="#">Wada ukryta / Inherent Vice (2014)</a></div><br>
        <div class="values">
            <div class="desc">
                <span id="text">W życiu prywatnego detektywa Doca Sportello niespodziewanie pojawia się jego była żona. Raczy go przy okazji opowieścią o swoim aktualnym chłopaku, deweloperze-miliarderze, w którym akurat jest zakochana, oraz snutej przez jego żonę i jej kochanka intrydze mającej na celu porwanie miliard... 
                <span class="more"><a href="#">[ Więcej ] »</a></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="img">
                <img width="150px" border="0" class="value" height="200px" src="http://zalukaj.tv/image/22139.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="float: right;">
                TEKST 1
            </div>
            <div style="">
                TEKST2
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="movie">
        <div class="Movie_Title"><a href="#">Wada ukryta / Inherent Vice (2014)</a></div><br>
        <div class="values">
            <div class="desc">
                <span id="text">W życiu prywatnego detektywa Doca Sportello niespodziewanie pojawia się jego była żona. Raczy go przy okazji opowieścią o swoim aktualnym chłopaku, deweloperze-miliarderze, w którym akurat jest zakochana, oraz snutej przez jego żonę i jej kochanka intrydze mającej na celu porwanie miliard... 
                <span class="more"><a href="#">[ Więcej ] »</a></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="img">
                <img width="150px" border="0" class="value" height="200px" src="http://zalukaj.tv/image/22139.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="float: right;">
                TEKST2
            </div>
            <div style="">
                <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And CSS code:

```
#RightBox {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
margin-top: 1%;
padding: 2%;
border: 1px solid #D1EAF8;
width: 30%;
background: #FCFDFE;
float: right;
}

#movie {
padding: 1%;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
width: 60%;
border: 1px solid grey;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-khtml-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px; 
margin-top: 4%;
}

#movie .Movie_Title a:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
}

#movie .Movie_Title a
{
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #33A1DE;
}

#movie .values {
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#movie .values .img {
padding: 1px;
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
}

#movie .values .img .value {
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#movie .values .desc {
padding-right: 2px;
width: 72%;
height: 200px;
float: right;
display: table;
}

#movie .values .desc .more a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}


#movie .values .desc .more a{
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
text-decoration:  none;
}

#movie .values .desc #text {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/snpggaj2/).

On the left side we can see two divs (look into a DEMO and use scroll). First div is so tight and I don't know where is a problem. Second div is OK.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code does the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/3yja4tLj/

```
<div id="content" style="float:left">
<div id="RightBox"><div class="Title">Informacje</div><br>Autokoder.pl jest obecnie najbardziej innowacyjną i najszybciej rozwijającą się aplikacją służącą do obsługi aukcji Allegro.<br><br>Z naszego serwisu mogą korzystać zarówno sprzedający jak i kupujący użytkownicy Allegro. Zapewniamy dla naszych użytkowników szeroki wybór usług płatnych oraz darmowych.<br><br>Tylko u nas masz pewność, że Twoje kody zostaną bezproblemowo dostarczone do klienta. Dbamy także o dobro Twoje i kupującego informując błyskawicznie poprzez e-mail o braku dostępnych kodów.<br><br>Autokoder.pl jest obecnie najbardziej innowacyjną i najszybciej rozwijającą się aplikacją służącą do obsługi aukcji Allegro.<br><br>Z naszego serwisu mogą korzystać zarówno sprzedający jak i kupujący użytkownicy Allegro. Zapewniamy dla naszych użytkowników szeroki wybór usług płatnych oraz darmowych.<br><br>Tylko u nas masz pewność, że Twoje kody zostaną bezproblemowo dostarczone do klienta. Dbamy także o dobro Twoje i kupującego informując błyskawicznie poprzez e-mail o braku dostępnych kodów.</div>
<div id="movies" style="float: left; width: 60%">
        <div id="movie">
            <div class="Movie_Title"><a href="#">Wada ukryta / Inherent Vice (2014)</a></div><br>
            <div class="values">
                <div class="desc">
                    <span id="text">W życiu prywatnego detektywa Doca Sportello niespodziewanie pojawia się jego była żona. Raczy go przy okazji opowieścią o swoim aktualnym chłopaku, deweloperze-miliarderze, w którym akurat jest zakochana, oraz snutej przez jego żonę i jej kochanka intrydze mającej na celu porwanie miliard... 
                    <span class="more"><a href="#">[ Więcej ] »</a></span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="img">
                    <img width="150px" border="0" class="value" height="200px" src="http://zalukaj.tv/image/22139.jpg">
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="float: right;">
                    <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
                </div>
                <div style="">
                    <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="movie">
            <div class="Movie_Title"><a href="#">Wada ukryta / Inherent Vice (2014)</a></div><br>
            <div class="values">
                <div class="desc">
                    <span id="text">W życiu prywatnego detektywa Doca Sportello niespodziewanie pojawia się jego była żona. Raczy go przy okazji opowieścią o swoim aktualnym chłopaku, deweloperze-miliarderze, w którym akurat jest zakochana, oraz snutej przez jego żonę i jej kochanka intrydze mającej na celu porwanie miliard... 
                    <span class="more"><a href="#">[ Więcej ] »</a></span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="img">
                    <img width="150px" border="0" class="value" height="200px" src="http://zalukaj.tv/image/22139.jpg">
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="float: right;">
                    <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
                </div>
                <div style="">
                    <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
            </div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>


#RightBox {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
margin-top: 1%;
padding: 2%;
border: 1px solid #D1EAF8;
width: 30%;
background: #FCFDFE;
float: right;
}

#movie {
padding: 1%;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid grey;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-khtml-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px; 
margin-top: 4%;
}


#movie .Movie_Title a:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
}

#movie .Movie_Title a
{
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #33A1DE;
}

#movie .values {
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#movie .values .img {
padding: 1px;
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
}

#movie .values .img .value {
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#movie .values .desc {
padding-right: 2px;
width: 62%;
height: 200px;
float: right;
display: table;
}

#movie .values .desc .more a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}


#movie .values .desc .more a{
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
text-decoration:  none;
}

#movie .values .desc #text {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: First I wrapped everything in the content div. Then I also wrapped the movies divs in the movies div and I modified the CSS for the movie div to have the width as 100%. Mark my answer as the solution to your problem pls. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following code, hope it will work :)

```css
#RightBox {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:'Century Gothic';
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #D1EAF8;
    width: 30%;
    background: #FCFDFE;
    float: right;
}
#movie {
    padding: 1%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:'Century Gothic';
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -khtml-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin-top: 4%;
}
#movie .Movie_Title a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#movie .Movie_Title a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #33A1DE;
}
#movie .values {
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#movie .values .img {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#movie .values .img .value {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#movie .values .desc {
    padding-right: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#movie .values .desc .more a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#movie .values .desc .more a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#movie .values .desc #text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="RightBox">


    <div class="Title">Informacje</div>
    <br>Autokoder.pl jest obecnie najbardziej innowacyjną i najszybciej rozwijającą sięa aplikacją służącą do obsługi aukcji Allegro.
    <br>
    <br>Z naszego serwisu mogą korzystać zarówno sprzedający jak i kupujący użytkownicy Allegro. Zapewniamy dla naszych użytkowników szeroki wybór usług płatnych oraz darmowych.
    <br>
    <br>Tylko u nas masz pewność, że Twoje kody zostaną bezproblemowo dostarczone do klienta. Dbamy także o dobro Twoje i kupującego informując błyskawicznie poprzez e-mail o braku dostępnych kodów.
    <br>
    <br>Autokoder.pl jest obecnie najbardziej innowacyjną i najszybciej rozwijającą się aplikacją służącą do obsługi aukcji Allegro.
    <br>
    <br>Z naszego serwisu mogą korzystać zarówno sprzedający jak i kupujący użytkownicy Allegro. Zapewniamy dla naszych użytkowników szeroki wybór usług płatnych oraz darmowych.
    <br>
    <br>Tylko u nas masz pewność, że Twoje kody zostaną bezproblemowo dostarczone do klienta. Dbamy także o dobro Twoje i kupującego informując błyskawicznie poprzez e-mail o braku dostępnych kodów.</div>
<div id="movie">
    <div class="Movie_Title"><a href="#">Wada ukryta / Inherent Vice (2014)</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="values">
        <div class="img">
            <img width="150px" border="0" class="value" height="200px" src="http://zalukaj.tv/image/22139.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="desc"> <span id="text">W życiu prywatnego detektywa Doca Sportello niespodziewanie pojawia się jego była żona. Raczy go przy okazji opowieścią o swoim aktualnym chłopaku, deweloperze-miliarderze, w którym akurat jest zakochana, oraz snutej przez jego żonę i jej kochanka intrydze mającej na celu porwanie miliard... 
     <span class="more"><a href="#">[ Więcej ] »</a></span></span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
        </div>
        <div style="">
            <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="movie">
    <div class="Movie_Title"><a href="#">Wada ukryta / Inherent Vice (2014)</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="values">
        <div class="img">
            <img width="150px" border="0" class="value" height="200px" src="http://zalukaj.tv/image/22139.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="desc"> <span id="text">W życiu prywatnego detektywa Doca Sportello niespodziewanie pojawia się jego była żona. Raczy go przy okazji opowieścią o swoim aktualnym chłopaku, deweloperze-miliarderze, w którym akurat jest zakochana, oraz snutej przez jego żonę i jej kochanka intrydze mającej na celu porwanie miliard... 
     <span class="more"><a href="#">[ Więcej ] »</a></span></span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
        </div>
        <div style="">
            <div style="width: 140px; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #33A1DE; color: #000; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">OGLĄDAJ FILM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: what do you want to do? can you please explain briefly? sorry I didn't get that clearly

Comment: Please check now, I've edited the post. I think this will help.